# How can i convert a uint32_t to a char* type

Tags: c++, c, char, arduino, uint32-t

Hello i am using an Arduino UNO with an adafruit shield to display score values but the function used to display scores only accepts char* values and the score itself can occupy up to 6 digits(000,000 to 999,999). i have tried using sprint() but i have had no luck since the screen will flicker like crazy. i believe the problem to be that chars only hold a certain number of bytes that could not fit a 32 bit int but i would think their is a way around this. draw text is the function used by the shield to drawstuff on the screen with input being char*, color code, size, x pixel, y pixel. if anybody can please help me convert between these two types please let me know. also if their are alternatives that would also help me.

my code:

```
char* textToWrite;
uint32_t currentScore = 0;
uint32_t highScore = 0;
highScore = currentScore;
sprintf(textToWrite,"%d.%d.%d.%d\0", currentScore);//sprint f not working properly right now
drawText(textToWrite, ST7735_WHITE, 1, 100, 10);
```

i have also tried using:

```
sprintf(textToWrite,"&#37;u", currentScore);
```

Comment: You *do* allocate space for `textToWrite` somewhere before you call `sprintf`?

Comment: Besides that, you might want to learn about the bitwise operators, like right shift `>>` and bitwise and `&`.

Comment: And you don't have to add the terminator, `sprintf` will do that for you.

Comment: Also, you have 4 `%d` and only 1 parameter after format.

Comment: @joachim nope i forgot but maybe i am not doing this correctly:realloc(textToWrite, sizeof(uint32_t));

Comment: No! sizeof(uint32_t) is 4. Just use an array, as in the answer

Comment: That okay, *if* `textToWrite` have been previously allocated (by e.g. `malloc`) or is `NULL`.

Comment: i'll give malloc a try but in the meantime the below answer seems to work.

Comment: Related: [Issues converting an uint32_t into a char*](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/79457/7113).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
char textToWrite[ 16 ];
uint32_t currentScore = 42;
// as per comment from LS_dev, platform is int 16bits
sprintf(textToWrite,"%lu", currentScore);
```

Comment: Argh so close if the score does reach 999,999 then the screen prints out 16,959

Comment: Arduino `int` is 16-bit. To print 32-bit integers `%lu` must be used.

Comment: @LS_dev ok this works when i use %lu thank you LS_dev and manuell

Comment: @manuell Because you are using your code within as 32-bit architecture.

Comment: unfortunately my reputation is too low to up vote this so please forgive me. @LS_dev yeah i forgot arduino is 16 bit and some stuff will be affected by this.

Comment: Consider the portable `#include <inttypes.h> sprintf(textToWrite,"%" PRIu32, currentScore);`  or `sprintf(textToWrite,"%lu", (unsigned long) currentScore);`